# R 3.5, Ubuntu 18.04, Error: Unable to establish connection with R session

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, ubuntu-18.04

I've got a fresh install of the three things on my Linux testbed laptop; `Ubuntu 18.04`, `R 3.5`, `R Studio 1.1.453`.

I can open a fresh instance of R Studio with nothing loaded. Let it sit idle for an hour. Then when I run any command I get `Error: Unable to establish connection with R session`.

I am able to use R Studio normally for ~30 or so minutes before this *lost connection* issue starts happening.

Any ideas what is happening and what to do about it?

Comment: I have been got the same error. I don't find yet a solution. But, at R terminal it works.

Comment: Apparently, the preview release works ok. I'm testing now.

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2909